# C compiler errors

Tags: c

I'm writing one of my first C programs. I'm trying to modify Ritchie and Kernighan's early tutorial on Farhenheith and Celsius conversion, but I'm getting errors I can't solve.

My goal is to run `./a.out fahr 20` and for the script to print out a conversion of Farhenheit temperatures starting at 20 (and going to 300) to Celsius.

But if I write `./a.out celsius 0` the script will print out a conversion of Celsius temperatures starting at 0 (and going to 300) to Fahrenheit.

Here's the current script (and below it are the errors I'm getting from the compiler).

I think there are a lot of errors, but I'm just starting to learn and grateful for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    float fahr, celsius;
    int upper, step; 

    upper = 300;
    step = 20; 


    if (strcmp("fahr", argv[1] == 0)){
        fahr = argv[2];
        while (fahr <= upper){
            fahr_conversion(fahr);
            fahr = fahr + step;
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp("celsius", argv[1] == 0)){
        celsius = argv[2]; 
        while (celsius <= upper){
            cels_conversion(celsius);
            celsius = celsius + step;
        }
    }
}

int fahr_conversion(float fahr){
        float celsius;
        celsius = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahr - 32.0);
        printf("%3.0f -> %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);

}
int cels_conversion(float celsius){
        float fahr;
        fahr = (celsius + (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32.0;
        printf("%3.0f -> %6.1f\n", celsius, fahr);
}
```

Errors:

```
    Far-Cels-Converter $ cc main.c 
main.c:16:21: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int'
      to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
        if (strcmp("fahr", argv[1] == 0)){
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/string.h:77:39: note: passing argument to parameter here
int      strcmp(const char *, const char *);
                                          ^
main.c:17:8: error: assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'char *'
                fahr = argv[2];
                     ^ ~~~~~~~
main.c:19:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fahr_conversion' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                        fahr_conversion(fahr);
                        ^
main.c:23:29: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int'
      to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
        else if (strcmp("celsius", argv[1] == 0)){
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/string.h:77:39: note: passing argument to parameter here
int      strcmp(const char *, const char *);
                                          ^
main.c:24:11: error: assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'char *'
                celsius = argv[2]; 
                        ^ ~~~~~~~
main.c:26:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cels_conversion' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                        cels_conversion(celsius);
                        ^
main.c:32:5: error: conflicting types for 'fahr_conversion'
int fahr_conversion(float fahr){
    ^
main.c:19:4: note: previous implicit declaration is here
                        fahr_conversion(fahr);
                        ^
main.c:38:5: error: conflicting types for 'cels_conversion'
int cels_conversion(float celsius){
    ^
main.c:26:4: note: previous implicit declaration is here
                        cels_conversion(celsius);
                        ^
4 warnings and 4 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some various errors here.

```
main.c:16:21: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int'
      to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
        if (strcmp("fahr", argv[1] == 0)){
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The parentheses are simply wrong. It should be `if (strcmp("fahr", argv[1]) == 0`).

```
main.c:17:8: error: assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'char *'
                fahr = argv[2];
                     ^ ~~~~~~~
```

You can't assign a string to a float, you have to use some function to convert it. E.g. `fahr = strtof(argv[2], 0)`. You need to include the header `<stdlib.h>` for `strtof`.

```
main.c:19:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fahr_conversion' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                        fahr_conversion(fahr);
                        ^
```

When `main` uses `fahr_conversion` before `fahr_conversion` appears in the source, the compiler doesn't yet know the type of `fahr_conversion`, so it assumes a standard type (which almost always is not what you want). This is solved by adding a function prototype *before* main:

```
int fahr_conversion(float fahr);
```

Though, I wonder whether `int` really is the return type you want. If you aren't returning anything, the return type should be `void`.

Comment: Great I think I'm almost there: but I'm getting this warning: `main.c:21:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strtof' is invalid in
      C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                fahr = strtof(argv[2], 0);`

Comment: Right, you need the `<stdlib.h>` header for `strtof`.

Answer (score 4):

Make it `if (strcmp("fahr", argv[1]) == 0)`  
The placement of closing parenthesis is wrong, hence the error 
 Similarly, change the else if condition to 
 `(strcmp("celsius", argv[1]) == 0)`  
 Also, your variable `fahr` is float, where as you are assigning it to argv[2], which is of char* type, hence you getting an error. 
 So you need to convert char* to float or double. `atof` function will help you out here. Try this 
  `fahr=atof(argv[2]);`
 Make sure you include `stdlib` header file.

Comment: Glad I could help :) If that solved your problem, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: Well, I'm still getting this error: `main.c:17:8: error: assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'char *'
                fahr = argv[2];` and this one: `main.c:32:5: error: conflicting types for 'fahr_conversion'
int fahr_conversion(float fahr){`

Comment: made the required changes, please have a look

Answer (score 2):

First, you want to test if the first parameter was a "fahr" string. So you should do:
compare strings:

```
strcmp("fahr", argv[1])
```

test the comparision result

```
strcmp("fahr", argv[1]) == 0
```

and perform action dependant on the test result

```
if( strcmp("fahr", argv[1]) == 0) {.....}
```

Find out the difference to your code!

Second, you want to take a second parameter as a numeric value. Alas it is a character string! You will not get appropriate result by assigning the string to a `float` variable. You need some strig-to-float convertion function. On of possibilities is `atof()`:

```
fahr = atof( argv[2] );
```

Comment: Great, almost there but I'm getting: `main.c:29:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'atof' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                fahr = atof( argv[2] );` when using `atof()`

Comment: @Jeff The function belongs to a standard C library, you can include the function declaration by adding the `#include <stdlib.h>` somewhere at the beginning of your code (preferably in the first line, before any other declarations).